# Adding form action to Stripe Custom Checkout

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have the script below I am just trying to figure out how I can send the form to a file on my server. The form action I am using is not working. The current page refreshes after the stripe action is finished instead of going to checkout_payment.php.

```
<form action="checkout_payment.php" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="customButton">Buy Now</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#customButton").click(function(){
                if(isInt($("#quantity").val())){
                    var token = function(res){
                        var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
                        $('form').append($input).submit();
                    };
                    StripeCheckout.open({
                        key: '<?php echo $stripe["publishable"];?>',
                        image: 'img/sgc.png',
                        amount: total,
                        currency: 'usd',
                        name: 'store',
                        description: '<?php echo ucfirst($product_name); ?>',
                        address: '',
                        email: '<?php echo $useremail;?>',
                        panelLabel:  'Checkout',
                        token: token
                      });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please put button type in your button code. Like below.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="customButton">Buy Now</button>
```

Afte that it will go to form action page.